# How to add a health endpoint in existing AEM Quickstart JAR?

Tags: java, docker, jar, aem, osgi-bundle

I have AEM 6.4 Quickstart JAR to work on AEM OSGI bundles. I am trying to deploy this JAR file using docker.

I am successful in deploying this JAR using docker but our cloud platform services give us a random IP and PORT for each & every new deployment.

In order to fetch a static IP and PORT, we need to configure a health check endpoint inside this JAR so that our NGINX manages to map the random IP & PORT to a static IP & PORT.

So my question is:

1. Can I unpack the Quickstart JAR and do something such that whenever the Quickstart JAR is deployed and if I hit "http://:/health" it should give me the status JSON as `{"status":"UP"}`?
2. Also, if I cant do above thing, then can I wrap the existing Quickstart JAR into a new JAR, and add a health endpoint in the new JAR, which gives me the status JSON as `{"status":"UP"}`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't get it. Docker with forward requests to AEM. You will always have to know the IP. You need something like a discovery service to orchestrate your containers.

Comment: There was a talk at this years adaptTo-conference about /systemready and /systemalive endpoints. The video of it will be online soon (~ 2-3 weeks). Maybe this helps a little and gives an overview. https://adapt.to/2018/en/schedule/system-readiness-framework-makes-deployment-automation-a-breeze.html